# A Java Web App with Servlets, JSP and Session: shopping cart example

Tags: java, servlets, e-commerce, jsp

This is the only Servlet I have:

```java
package com.tugay.shopping;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * User: koraytugay
 * Date: 28/09/14
 * Time: 14:29
 */

@WebServlet(name = "shoppingServlet", urlPatterns = "/shop")
public class ShoppingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    final Map<Integer, String> products = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        products.put(1, "Sandpaper");
        products.put(2, "Nails");
        products.put(3, "Glue");
        products.put(4, "Paint");
        products.put(5, "Tape");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = req.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null)
            action = "browse";

        switch (action) {
            case "addToCart":
                this.addToCart(req, resp);
                break;
            case "viewCart":
                this.viewCart(req, resp);
                break;
            case "empty":
                this.empty(req, resp);
                break;
            case "browse":
                this.browse(req, resp);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void empty(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("cart");
        browse(req, resp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void viewCart(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> cart = (Map<String, Integer>) req.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
        req.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/viewCart.jsp")
                .forward(req, resp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void addToCart(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Integer productId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("productId"));

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
            session.setAttribute("cart", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        }

        Map<String, Integer> cart = (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");

        if (cart.containsKey(products.get(productId))) {
            cart.put(products.get(productId), cart.get(products.get(productId)) + 1);
        } else
            cart.put(products.get(productId), 1);

        resp.sendRedirect("shop?action=viewCart");

    }

    private void browse(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("products", products);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/browse.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**viewCart.jsp:**

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>You have these items in your cart:</h1>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.cart}" var="cartItem">
    ${cartItem.key}  - ${cartItem.value}
    <br />
</c:forEach>
<a href="<c:url value="/shop"><c:param name="action" value="browse" /></c:url>">Back to Browse</a>
<a href="<c:url value="/shop"><c:param name="action" value="empty" /></c:url>">Empty Cart</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**browse.jsp:**

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click on the product to add product to your cart:</h1>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.products}" var="product">
    <a href="<c:url value="/shop">
        <c:param name="action" value="addToCart"/>
        <c:param name="productId" value="${product.key}"/>
        </c:url>">${product.value}</a>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
            <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jsf</include-prelude>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
            <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You'll get better reviews if you take a little time to explain what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem more natural to initialize the `products` map in the constructor instead of an `init` method:

```
private final Map<Integer, String> products;

public ShoppingServlet() {
    products = new HashMap<>();
    products.put(1, "Sandpaper");
    products.put(2, "Nails");
    products.put(3, "Glue");
    products.put(4, "Paint");
    products.put(5, "Tape");
}
```

---

Instead of checking if `action` is null and setting to a default,
you could add a `default` in the `switch` to handle that:

```
String action = req.getParameter("action");

switch (action) {
    case "addToCart":
        this.addToCart(req, resp);
        break;
    case "viewCart":
        this.viewCart(req, resp);
        break;
    case "empty":
        this.empty(req, resp);
        break;
    case "browse":
    default:
        this.browse(req, resp);
}
```

---

Instead of duplicating string literals like `"cart"` in multiple places,
it would be better to use constant variables, for example:

```
private static final String KEY_CART = "cart";
```

This would make future changes easier and avoid some errors,
and also help with typing, because you can autocomplete variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be concerned about thread safety in web applications, HashMap is not thread safe so you can use the `Concurrent` version.

```
private final Map<Integer, String> products = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I added `private` to the declaration, because sharing mutable state is not a good idea.

```
Integer productId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("productId"));// DODGY!
```

This code here is a bit dodgy, you shouldnt never trust values you getting from the `request`, so you got to handle the exception and refuse the request if the value is not parsable to `Integer`

Comment: @KorayTugay You welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. Its often a good idea in OOP to use Objects, so why dont have a Cart-Session-Bean?
2. I think `<el-ignored>` is off by default.
3. `ConcurrentHashMap` ok, but afaik we only read from products... So i guess no loop will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because all `put` is done. You better use `Hashtable` because it does not allow a `null` as value. But on the cart you realy shall use the `ConcurrentHashMap`!
4. <del>30 seconds are very tiny, we actually use 5 hours. even my online-bank uses 5 minutes.</del>
5. Keep care of async calles like SleimanJneidi said because if ....

   ```
   if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
       session.setAttribute("cart", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
   }
   // <!-- ... someone call "empty" right here, you have a NPE then!!!!
   Map<String, Integer> cart = (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");
   ```
6. `resp.sendRedirect("shop?action=viewCart");` do not need the `shop` prefix.
7. Firms like **TÜV** and **TrustedShops** discourage from have unused arguments, they like you to have blamed them, so check `request.getParameterMap().size()==1`.
8. No need to set the indexes for the map.
9. I realy like xml, therefore i love to use expression-language. If you like xml too, use `<c:url var="shopBaseURL" value="/shop" />`

Comment: I think this is 30 minutes?        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>

Comment: What do you mean by No need to set the indexes for the map. ?